# HTML5 canvas versus flash

Tags: html, flash, canvas

Our website has a graphical reporting component which has its UI already developed as flash component. We are planning to replace it with the new HTML5 canvas element, in order to support mobile browsers as well. I do have a perception that flash runtime runs as a sandbox inside the browser, which doesn't block the other HTML components while doing any complex job.

I'm wondering, can I achieve the same behaviour, without compromising on the performance by replacing the flash component with HTML5 canvas. Please give me some inputs to consider.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Web workers let you spawn background threads to do tasks like data fetches from the server and intensive calculations and long-running offscreen canvas renderings.

However you need to test your specific code because the cost of multi-thread communication and synchronization may well be more costly than just letting the code run on a single thread.

This is especially true on the mobile devices that don't have multiple processors and therefore can't do parallel processing.  Recent mobile devices are starting to have multiple processors, but most existing mobile devices in service do not.

Html canvas is able to use the GPU to automatically enhance graphics processing.  So recent mobile devices that have GPUs will automatically have enhanced graphics processing without coding on your part.

Bottom line: code a quick-and-dirty prototype of your UI and test it on a mobile device.